# One PHP form saves to MySQL, another doesn't, not sure why

Tags: php, mysql

We have a PHP website with multiple forms that save to a database. We have two pages which both save similar information. One saves all of this information correctly. The second, which I'm trying to correct, fails to save one of the fields, area_info.

Should it be as simple as me editing the .php files and copying the UPDATE statement from the one that works and put it in the one that doesn't?

Inspecting the element on the non-working page, the text box for the field that isn't saving appears as:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="area_info[10]">
```

On the working page, after I put in TestingAgain as the value and hit save, the same field is:

```
<input type="text" size="25" value="TestingAgain" name="area_info[1]">
```

Here's the code pasted

Doesn't work

```
$get_area_id_sql = "
    SELECT   area_id
    FROM     areas
    WHERE    contest_id = $contest_id ";

    $get_area_id = mysql_query($get_area_id_sql) or die($get_area_id_sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_area_id)) {
    $ar_id = $row['area_id'];
    $ar_info = $area_info[$ar_id];

    if (isset($area_info[$ar_id])) {

        $ar_info_update_sql = "
        UPDATE  tracking.areas
        SET area_info = \"$ar_info\"
        WHERE   area_id = \"$ar_id\" ";

        mysql_query($ar_info_update_sql) or die($ar_info_update_sql);
```

Does work for field but in a different PHP file

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    if(trim($area_name[$x]) <> $null) {
if($area_id[$x] <> $null) {
    $sql = "UPDATE tracking.areas 
                        SET area_name    = '{$area_name[$x]}', 
                            area_info    = '{$area_info[$x]}',
                            area_sort    = '{$area_sort[$x]}', 
                            contest_id           = '{$contest_id}',
                            tracking_id      = '{$tracking_id}'
                        WHERE area_id    = '{$area_id[$x]}' ";
} 
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tracking.areas 
                            (area_name, 
                            area_info,
                            area_sort, 
                            contest_id,
                            tracking_id) 
                        VALUES 
                            ('{$area_name[$x]}', 
                            '{$area_info[$x]}',
                            '{$area_sort[$x]}', 
                            '{$contest_id}',
                            '{$tracking_id}') ";

}
```

Comment: On another note, the mysql_* functions are deprecated and are not advisable to use. Have a look at PDO or mysqli_* instead... and what does the variable `$null` contain? How and where is it declared?

Comment: They're different enough from the defunct mysql_ functions to where that invalidates the whole question. You've got some rewriting to do.

Comment: Does `$area_name[$x]` have a value?

Comment: `or die($get_area_id_sql)`? Seems like an endless loop if it fails.

Comment: So firstly, does it satisfy the `isset(area_info['ar_id'])` condition?

Comment: No Fred, it will just print present the string within that variable and then kill the script.

Comment: @entiendoNull Ok. However, it's usually best to check for the actual error, if any exist.

Comment: Doing both is good practise for debugging... using the old functions (as being used by thread owner) would look something like this: `or die (mysql_error().' QueryString: '.$get_area_id_sql)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone.  This is an old legacy site/system I've inherited, written by someone no longer with us (RIP), and he never really documented much.  So hoping somehow I can fuddle through figuring this out with the experts of SO help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Specify what $contest_id is! 
$sq = "SELECT area_id FROM areas WHERE contest_id ='".$contest_id."'";
$qu = mysql_query($sq) or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($fe = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu)) {
    if (isset($_POST['area_info'][$fe['area_id']])) {
        $sql = "UPDATE tracking.areas SET area_info ='".$_POST['area_info'][$fe['area_id']]."' WHERE area_id ='".$fe['area_id']."'";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Careful suggesting PHP short tags. Versions prior to PHP 5.5 usually have to have this turned on manually in the php.ini file. This is not normally a default...

Comment: How can I tell what version of PHP I'm running?  That might be helpful but I'm not sure how to find it to tell you guys.

Comment: Thanks, I shall update the short tag. This was just my habit.

Comment: You can comment it out with /* */ tags, the only differences between the two are this: `$ar_info = $area_info[$ar_id];` I did not see where you were getting `$area_info[]` so I instead pulled the array off the request variable `$_POST['area_info'][]`. You just need to make sure that you are sending this `$contest_id` in order for it to work.

Comment: @DanceSC Thanks, and sorry for at'ing the wrong person when I replied!

Comment: No problem, you have the name of the input field as `area_info[10]` which suggested that you needed to use an array. If you don't need the array, you could change the name to 'area_info' and in your sql statement use `area_info ='".$_POST['area_info']."' `

Comment: @DanceSC I think this worked!!!  It now saves it appears.  I'm going to test it out more thoroughly and in more situations to confirm, but I think you did it!!  I can't even begin to explain how grateful I am, I'm literally grinning from ear to ear.

Comment: @BP09 I'm glad to hear this! Is there anything else I can help with?

Comment: @DanceSC After more testing, I think we're good!  Although I don't totally understand how you figured out this is the solution or which part actually fixed it.  If you have time, could you explain it a bit more?  If not, that's fine too, I'm just trying to learn both the thought process and the coding behind it.

Comment: @BP09 Whichever value you put in the name field for the input, for example if you have `name='this'` then when you submit the form you pull it using either `$_GET['this']`, `$_POST['this']`, or `$_REQUEST['this']` depending on the form type. Your name field was set to `area_info[10]` and the brackets mean it is an array. So to pull it you would instead type `$_GET['area_info[10]']` but because that is not how it works, the brackets have to go on the outside: `$_GET['area_info'][10]`

Comment: @DanceSC Thanks.  I have so much to learn with this stuff, but having that explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should be using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` to wrap strings. Double quotes may work depending on your MySQL configuration, but single quotes is better.

So the update you need:

```
$ar_info_update_sql = "
        UPDATE  tracking.areas
        SET area_info = '{$ar_info}'
        WHERE   area_id = '{$ar_id'}'";
```

Also note that I wrapped your variables in curly brackets, IMO this is better practice and it also allows inserting non-trivial variables into your strings, e.g.

```
$a = "This is a {$array['some_index']}";
$b = "And that is a {$someObj->someProperty}";
$c = "And then we have {$someObj->someFUnction()}";
```

Comment: Thanks!  You know, I did notice the curly bracket difference between the two, but really I had no idea how impactful those may or may not be.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use that bit of code, the page won't even load anything.  Not sure why though. @Populus